# Doctrine 2 error ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine-orm, oracle11g

I'm using **Doctrine 2** and **Yii** and `Oracle`.

I have a `DateTime` field

```
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CREATE_DATE", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createDate;
```

I used this code to insert person to the table

```
        $date = new \DateTime("now");
        $person = new Person();
        $person->setCreateDate($date);
        $person->setLastName('name');
        $entityManager->persist($person);
        $entityManager->flush();
```

but it return this error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO PERSON (PERSON_ID, CREATE_DATE, LAST_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [27, "2014-10-29 09:23:38", "name"]:

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

please help me.

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930670/doctrine-2-oracle-datetme-column-showing-not-a-valid-month-on-insert-entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by execute this:

```
   $em  = $this->getEntityManager();
   $dbh = $em->getConnection();
   $sth = $dbh->prepare("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS' NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'");
   $sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone is using **Doctrine with Symfony**, it's much easier. Just need 2 EventListeners and activate them in the service definition as per this gist -
 https://gist.github.com/phpfour/4290cc1f0892dda4ef94a492d6b3f81e